# CakePHP data in other language is created in database more then once

Tags: database, cakephp, model, multilingual

Every language specific record is saved in original (table name: categories) and translation (table name: category_i18n) table. I just want to save one record in the original table and refer to from the translation table for each language specific record. I'm not sure this is the intended behavior of `CakePHP` or that I'm doing something wrong.

I followed the [`TranslateBehavior`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html) steps to set up a multilingual system.

### Here an example of what happens when I save a record

**Saving data in English:**

1) In `admin_add.ctp` I fill the form and choose language English (`local = "eng"`);

2) My record is saved in the database as following:

*table categories:*

```
id | created | modified | total_services
1  | 2014-08-15 09:09:20 | 2014-08-15 09:09:20 | 0
```

*table category_i18ns*

```
id | created | modified | locale | model | foreign_key | field | content
1  | 2014-08-15 09:09:20 | 2014-08-15 09:09:20 | eng | Category | 1 | name | Location
1  | 2014-08-15 09:09:20 | 2014-08-15 09:09:20 | eng | Category | 1 | url_name | location
```

**Saving data in German:**

1) In `admin_add.ctp` I fill the form and choose language German (`local = "deu"`);

2) My record is saved in the database as following:

*table categories:*

```
id | created | modified | total_services
1  | 2014-08-15 09:09:20 | 2014-08-15 09:09:20 | 0
2  | 2014-08-15 09:11:11 | 2014-08-15 09:11:11 | 0
```

I don't want to save location multiple times in this table! I just want one record here and the language specific content in table `category_i18ns` with reference to this record.

*table category_i18ns*

```
id | created | modified | locale | model | foreign_key | field | content
1  | 2014-08-15 09:09:20 | 2014-08-15 09:09:20 | eng | Category | 1 | name | Location
2  | 2014-08-15 09:09:20 | 2014-08-15 09:09:20 | eng | Category | 1 | url_name | location
3  | 2014-08-15 09:11:11 | 2014-08-15 09:11:11 | deu | Category | 2 | name | Stelle
4  | 2014-08-15 09:11:11 | 2014-08-15 09:11:11 | deu | Category | 2 | url_name | stelle
```

### My code and database design

**Database**

*categories*

```
id: int
created: datetime
modified: datetime
total_services: int
```

*category_i18ns*

```
id: int
created: datatime
modified: datatime
locale: varchar
model: varchar
foreign_key: int
field: varchar
content: varchar
```

**CakePHP logic**

*Category.php*

```
<?php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Category extends AppModel {

    public $actsAs  = array(
        'Translate' => array(
            'name', 'url_name'
        )
    );

    public $translateModel = 'CategoryI18n';
    // public $translateTable = 'category_translations';

    public $hasMany = array('Service');

    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'alphaNumeric' => array(
                'rule' => '/[a-zA-Z0-9 ]/',
                'message' => 'Category can only contain alphabetic and numeric characters.'
            ),
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Category is mandatory.'
            )
        ),
        'url_name' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Category url is mandatory.'
            )
        ),
        'local' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Please choose one.',
                'allowEmpty' => false
            )
        )
    );

}
```

*CategoryI18n.php*

```
<?php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class CategoryI18n extends AppModel {

    public $displayField = "field";

}
```

*CategoriesController.php*

```
<?php

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class CategoriesController extends AppController {

    public function admin_index() {
        // $this->Category->locale = 'nld';
        $this->set('categories', $this->Category->find('all'));

        // Should be at the end!
        $this->render('admin/admin_index');
    }

    public function admin_add() {
        $this->helpers = array('Bootstrap', 'Navigation', 'Session');
        $this->components = array('Session');

        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            if(isset($this->data['Category']['local'])) {
                $this->Category->locale = $this->data['Category']['local'];
            }

            $this->Category->create();

            if($this->Category->save($this->request->data)) {
                debug('saved');
            }
        }
        $this->render('admin/admin_add');
    }

}
```

*admin_add.ctp*

```
<div class="container">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create(
        'Category',
        array('role' => 'form')
    ); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array(
        'div' => array('class' => 'form-group'),
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'required' => false
    )); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('url_name', array(
        'div' => array('class' => 'form-group'),
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'required' => false
    )); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Bootstrap->radio(
        'Category.local',
        $this->Navigation->languagesList('iso_alpha3', 'full'),
        array('required' => false, 'default' => 'eng')
    ); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->button('Add', array(
        'type' => 'submit',
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
    )); ?>

    <?php $this->Form->end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest reading about CakePHP's built in translate behavior -- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html  I think it does what you are wanting.

Comment: @Kai I did read and followed CakePHP's article about translate behavior. Please look at my updated question.